# $u(x,t)\cdot(\nabla\rho(x,t))$ versus $(u(x,t)\cdot\nabla)\rho(x,t)).$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, chain-rule, fluid-dynamics

**I am new in the Navier Stokes Equation**

In the Eulerian description of the fluid, if I have $g(t)=\rho(x(t),t)$, then:
$$g'(t)=\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}(x(t),t)+\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}(x(t),t)x'(t)=\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}(x(t),t)+ u(x,t)\cdot(\nabla\rho(x,t)).$$

$u(x,t)=x'(t)$ is the velocity field of the flow of the fluid, $\rho:\Omega×[0,T] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the mass density, and $\nabla$ is the nabla operator.

**MY QUESTION IS** how did
$u(x,t)\cdot (\nabla\rho(x,t))$ become $(u(x,t)\cdot\nabla)\rho(x,t))?$

I searched on internet and they said that:

> Generally the convective derivative of the field u·∇y, the one that contains the covariant derivative of the field, can be interpreted both as involving the streamline tensor derivative of the field u·(∇y), or as involving the streamline directional derivative of the field (u·∇) y, leading to the same result.

BUT I don't know why and how did this lead to the same result!!

Comment: If you write both expressions in components, you then see they are the same. What is the confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just because $\rho$ is a scalar function (i.e. takes values in $\mathbb R$). If you check
\begin{align} 
(\nabla \rho )_i &= \partial_i \rho,
\\
u\cdot\nabla &=\sum_i u_i \partial_i,
\end{align}
so
$$u\cdot (\nabla \rho) = \sum_i u_i \partial_i \rho = \sum_i(u_i \partial_i)\rho = (u\cdot\nabla) \rho.$$

The situation is slightly different if you were computing $g'$ for $g(t) = v(x(t),t)\in\mathbb R^n$. Then, you might wonder, what exactly is the meaning of
$$ u \cdot (\nabla v)?$$
In this case, $u$ is a vector, but $\nabla v$ is a matrix. As a matrix product, we have
$$ (u\cdot\nabla)v = (\nabla v)u.$$
The computation: writing components out in full (and using chain rule)
\begin{align} \frac d{dt} g_i'(t) 
&= \partial_t v_i(x,t) + \sum_j\partial_jv_i(x,t)\partial_t x_j  
\\&= \partial_t v_i(x,t) + \sum_j\partial_jv_i(x,t)u_j(x,t)  
\\&= \partial_t v_i(x,t) + \sum_ju_j(x,t)\partial_jv_i(x,t) \end{align}
In the last line you see exactly $\sum_ju_j(x,t)\partial_j =: u\cdot\nabla $ appear, and in the second last line, you see $\nabla v=( \partial_j v_i)_{i,j}$ multiplied on the right by the vector $u$. The two lines are equivalent because we wrote all the components out and at the level of scalars, everything commutes.

IMO $u\cdot(\nabla v)$ is dangerous notation in this case, it does not match the matrix product $u^T \nabla v$. Somehow it looks like you should be able to relate this with doing a "contraction" with the "left index" i.e. $a\cdot M := a_i M_{ij}$, but this is wrong because the Jacobian $(\nabla v)_{ij} = \delta_{\color{red} j} v_{\color{red} i}$ is the **other** way.

Comment: sorry but above you used the Dot Product isn't it? As if $u.v=u_iv_i$? But my question is what did we gain for $\rho$ being scalar? And how did $u_i \partial_i\rho =(u_i \partial_i)\rho$? Can you explain it more, please.

Comment: @user854662 Yes, dot product. Please, give me the definition of $(u_i\partial_i)\rho$? Isn't it exactly $u_i\partial_i \rho$? And if $\rho$ is not a scalar, then please see the second half of my answer

Comment: Can I take some of your time please to explain for me the **2nd case** and solve it more specifically? So that I could see the difference much more. And thank you so much!!

Comment: @user854662 can you explain what is second case? The vector case? I’m away from computer but I’ll check when I get back to my computer

Comment: Yes when you started saying: **The situation is slightly different if you were computing...** And thank you in advance.

Comment: @user854662 I have added to the answer, hope it helps

Comment: It really helped! But I am confused when (as you said) about the multiplication of $u\cdot(\nabla v)$, how to fix it!

Comment: And as a conclusion: $ (u\cdot\nabla)w = (\nabla w)u.$ , for all function $w$ mapped into $\mathbb{R^n}$ for all $n \ge 1$ , i.e in the scalar case (concerning $\rho$) and multidimensional case (concerning $v$), isn't it? Or because of your last IMO, it can't be true for $v$!! Even if the calculations are logical..

Comment: @user854662 it is true, but for $(u\cdot \nabla)v$, not $u\cdot(\nabla v)$. I would suggest to not write $u\cdot(\nabla v)$ in this case.

Comment: thank you so much!